# Add extension functions to a existing class without changing source code of class

Tags: c++

I have a big C++ application that uses the old version of a open source library. I want to upgrade to new library. In new libary a old function **fnOldFunction()** is removed and a new function **fnNewFunction()** is added. 
Now I have two choices:

1. Replace all the instances of fnOldFunction() with fnNewFunction(). I have many other functions like fnOldFunction(), I do not want deal with n functions with thousands of find and replacement.
2. I have source code of library. I can add fnOldFunction() there and call the fnNewFunction from fnOldFunction(). But even I have source code of that libray, do not want to make any changes in libray's source code.

Can anybody give me another way to achieve the same. I know some languages like Ruby, Javascript, Objective C provides the way to extend/modify the existing class without changing the source code of that class. But C++ lacks this feature.

Comment: C++ doesn't have extension methods. You literally cannot add members to a class except between the class definition's curly braces.

Comment: In the long run 1. will be preferred instead of hacks/tricks which will also  render your code less readable

Comment: @Brian: I know C++ do not have this feature, It is just suggestion that I am asking.

Comment: Write an adapter class that uses the external classes internally, hiding details from its clients. Then all changes are localised to your adapter class.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way may be to derive your own class from the library class and re-add to it all the old version's functions. This does not require writing a full adapter and it does not touch the library code. You only need to bulk rename for class name, which is less error-prone and scales better.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a macro for this porpuse.

```
class A {
public:
  void fnNewFunction() {}
};

int main(void) {
  A a;
  a.fnNewFunction();

#define fnOldFunction fnNewFunction

  a.fnOldFunction();
}
```

I **do not** advice to use this technique. This will screw the intellisense and might introduce bugs (what if there is a another class with both `fnOldFunction` and `fnNewFunction` defined?)

The reason I wrote this is because it answers your specific question.

Option 1 of yours is the preferred solution. You could easily use your editor's re-factoring facilities to perform this action in no-time.

Answer (score 0):

I think that's a good fit for *Policies*.

You could define two interfaces:

```
class A {
    void fnOldFunction();
public:
    void fn() {
        fnOldFunction();
    }
};
class B {
    void fnNewFunction();
public:
    void fn() {
        fnFunction();
    }
};
```

`A` and `B` could inherit from classes of the old/new library.
Now, you just have to define your working class like this:

```
template <typename Policy>
class C : public Policy {
    /* Whatever you need */
public:
    /* Say doSomething need to call fn */
    void doSomething() {
        /* Whatever */
        fn();
        /* ... */
    }
};
```

Now depending on your usecase, you could either use `C<A>` or `C<B>`. Note that this could be cumbersome if many names have changed in the library (breaking the API like that isn't a good idea, you have my sympathy :( ).

With this solution, which in terms does almost the same thing as @Alexander's one, you can still link against the old library as well as the new version. You just have to switch from `C<B>` to `C<A>`.

You could even couple that with other metaprogramming techniques such as type traits to make the compiler deduce if you need `C<A>` or `C<B>` all by itself. If possible, you wouldn't even have to touch the code to compile with either version of the lib.